# Can't get attribute value from the database while using CreateView and ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to create a form to add a blog to a subscription list of a logged in user. 
Right now I'm only interested in the first part of the form_valid till 'except'

```
class AddBlogToSubList(CreateView):
model = SubscriptionList
form_class = SubsListForm
template_name = 'blog/add_blog_to_sub_list.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:blog-list')

def form_valid(self, form):
    try:
        # first I'm trying to find out if an instance of a 
        # SubscriptionList model is in the database
        model_instance = self.request.user.subscription_list

        # Then I create an instance of a form with kwarg 'instance'
        # to work with the default model instance
        f = SubsListForm(self.request.POST, instance=model_instance)

        # As far as I understand here I get a instance of a model in
        # the database with the ability to update it as I've mentioned
        # earlier instance=model_instance
        existing_instance = f.save(commit=False)

        blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['blog_pk'])

        # update a subscription list of a current user with a new blog
        existing_instance.blogs_in_subscription.add(blog)

        # save an updated instance
        existing_instance.save()
        f.save_m2m()
        return super(AddBlogToSubList, self).form_valid(form)
    except SubscriptionList.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

The thing that I expect is that if I'm updating the instance of a SubscriptionList (dew to instance=model_instance, according to the django docs) that is already in the database the 'user' attribute will be already set. But I get this error:

```
    File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  328.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /blogs/3/add_to_subscription/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_subscriptionlist.user_id
```

forms

```
    from django.forms import ModelForm

from blog.models import SubscriptionList


class SubsListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SubscriptionList
        fields = []
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', BlogList.as_view(), name='blog-list'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/$', BlogDetail.as_view(), name='blog-detail'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/add_to_subscription/$', AddBlogToSubList.as_view(), name='add-to-subscription'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/subscriptions/$', SubscriptionListView.as_view(), name='subscription-list'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/create/$', PostCreate.as_view(), name='post-create'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/(?P<post_pk>\d+)/$', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/(?P<post_pk>\d+)/update/$', PostUpdate.as_view(), name='post-update'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/(?P<post_pk>\d+)/delete/$', PostDelete.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
```

]

models

```
class SubscriptionList(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                            related_name='subscription_list')
blogs_in_subscription = models.ManyToManyField(Blog, related_name='in_subscription_lists',
                                                blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s subscription list" % self.user.username
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why not simply `model_instance = form.save(commit=False)`??? If the object is new, `model_instance.pk` will be `None`, else you can fetch the current instance in the database using `SubscriptionList.objects.get(pk=model_instance.pk)` - do whatever you have to do and decide if you want to call `model_instance.save()`.

Comment: @PauloScardine Sorry, not quite understand you. As I see it, if i do this model_instance = form.save(commit=False) it will save a new SubscriptionList object. It has now information about the databse objects of this class, but I need to get an object of the class that is already in the database and update in, that is why i used 'instance=model_instance' or I miss something?

Comment: Perhaps I missed something, but `form.save(commit=False)` will give you a SubscriptionList object just BEFORE saving it . If it is a "create" operation, the pk attribute will be None, if it is an "update" the pk attribute will be the primary key for existing object with the changes from the form but not saved yet (with `commit==False` you must save it explicitly using `model_instance.save()`). If you want to compare with the record actually in the database, you must fetch it with  something like `old = SubscriptionList.objects.get(pk=model_instance.pk)`.